# Height of a container with floating children

Tags: html, css

This is  a basic design question, which has vexed me for along time.  Imagine this code:

```
<div style='background:#ccc;'>
    <ul> 
       <li style='display:block; float:left; width:50%;'> item 1 </li>
       <li style='display:block; float:left; width:50%;'> item 2 </li>
       <li style='display:block; float:left; width:50%;'> item 3 </li>
       <li style='display:block; float:left; width:50%;'> item 4 </li>
       <li style='display:block; float:left; width:50%;'> item 5 </li>
       <li style='display:block; float:left; width:50%;'> item 6 </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

The `<ul>` element will outgrow the container unless I set the containing div to also have the css properties of "float:left;"
(Please note that I do not style my elements inline, this is simply for the example).

Often, I work-around this by giving the container an explicit height... but this feels sloppy in a mobile world, and creates a lot of overhead: I must write media queries to control the height at various screen sizes.  What is the right way to have auto height on an element which contains floating elements?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set `overflow:auto` on the containing div:

```html
<div style='background:#ccc;overflow:auto;'>
    <ul> 
       <li style='display:block; float:left; width:50%;'> item 1 </li>
       <li style='display:block; float:left; width:50%;'> item 2 </li>
       <li style='display:block; float:left; width:50%;'> item 3 </li>
       <li style='display:block; float:left; width:50%;'> item 4 </li>
       <li style='display:block; float:left; width:50%;'> item 5 </li>
       <li style='display:block; float:left; width:50%;'> item 6 </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

When you float the children, the ancestor collapses and setting the overflow restores the behavior you're after.

Comment: Fast, and clean. Thank you.